# Function that returns only the even bits from a word

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying to make a function that takes as a parameter a 16 bits and returns only the even bits from it (even as indices), basically there should be returned  8 bits.

For example, if we have: yxyx yxyx yxyx yxyx;

The function should return: xxxx xxxx;

I am quite lost, but I started as:

```
unsigned char function(unsigned short int p){
   unsigned char q=0;
   for(int i=15;i>=0;i--){
      if(i%2==0){
         //now we have somehow to take that bit because it has an even index
      }
   }
return q;
}
```

Could you help me to finish this?

Comment: Have you seen how to extract a single bit from an integer if you know the index?

Comment: Try writing out two expressions: one that extracts the bit at index `i` from a number, and one that copies bit `i` from one number into another.

Comment: You should read about bitwise operators in C

Comment: @Zacky Not any special resource. For the operators, the Wikipedia is OK. Stackoverflow too

Comment: If I were you, I would use `uint16_t` instead of `unsigned short int`. It guarantees the 16 bits

Comment: Sorry, OT for this question but I do have a solution for MySQL 8 for your recent question if you're interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's multiple ways to write down this kind of algorithm. Here, I'm going with the easiest to understand. But first, let's change the signature of the function to use the correct types:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t function(uint16_t p);
```

We convert a 16-bit unsigned integer to an 8-bit one, so the above is the recommended signature. Now for the algorithm.

The central idea is to place the bit we want to extract to the right-most position so we can get it by using `& 1`, which will zero-out all bits except the first one. This:

```
uint8_t right_most_bit = p & 1;
```

will give us that bit. Now we want to store that bit at the correct position in `q`. There's gonna be some index `i` for that. So:

```
q = q | (right_most_bit << i);
```

or simply:

```
q |= (right_most_bit << i);
```

Then we need to put the next after the next bit of `p` to the right-most position. We do that with:

```
p = p >> 2;
```

or shorter:

```
p >>= 2;
```

So that leaves us with the problem of creating a loop so that our `i` is increased by 1 on each iteration. The loop should end when `p` is 0, since then we know there's not gonna be any more bits to extract. This has the benefit that the loop will only run for the minimum required amount of iterations. So

```
for (unsigned i = 0; p != 0; i++)
```

We put this all together:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; p != 0; i++) {
    uint8_t right_most_bit = p & 1;
    q |= (right_most_bit << i);
    p >>= 2;
}
```

Of course you can simplify this further:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; p != 0; i++, p >>= 2) {
    q |= ((p & 1) << i);
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
uint8_t function(uint16_t p)
{
    uint8_t q = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; p != 0; i++, p >>= 2) {
        q |= ((p & 1) << i);
    }
    return q;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This is useful for me. // One question: shouldn't this line  be: q |= (right_most_bit << i); (Instead of + a |).

Comment: @Zacky They do the same.  However, I agree that in this context, `|` makes more sense.

Comment: @Zacky I used `+` because I thought it would be easier to understand. I changed it to `|` now, since it seems `+` had the opposite effect and made it more confusing.

Comment: @Zacky Btw, `+` works because the algorithm is only ever adding powers of 2 to `q` which only contains a sum of lower powers of 2. And since powers of 2 always represent a single bit, addition works. `0101` + `1000` for example is `1101`, same as `0101` | `1000`.

Comment: This for (unsigned i = 0; p != 0; i++) is new for me, but I think I can diggest it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zacky Yep. The condition of a `for` loop can be anything you want. It doesn't have to be related to `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Use some bitwise operations:

```c
char f(short int p) {
    char ans = 0;
    for(int i = 14; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
        ans |= ((p >> i) & 1) << (i / 2);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Steps:

- Declare `ans` = `0000 0000`
- Loop `i` from 14 to 0 decreasing 2 every iteration

  - Isolate the bit you need by shifting and making an `&` (bitwise and) operation.

    - Example: `1100 0000 0000 0000` shifted 14 times to the right is equals `0000 0000 0000 0011`, now you `&` it with 1 (`0000 0000 0000 0001`) and you get `0000 0000 0000 0001`
  - Shift back `(i / 2)` (in this case, shift 7 times to the left) bits since your answer is 8 bits, not 16.

    - From the last example, `0000 0000 0000 0001` becomes `0000 0000 1000 0000`. The bit was isolated and now is in the correct position for the answer.
  - Now make `ans = ans | last-steps-result`, this gives us `0000 0000 | 1000 0000`, since this is an `or` the result is `1000 0000`
- Return `ans`

Comment: 14 is magic. You should maybe write it as `16 - 2` so that it's clearer why it's there

Comment: Never ever do shifting on signed variables! Also, pre-C99 types are not very nice for shifting purposes. How long is a `short int`?

Comment: Also, a `char` should only be used for characters. For any other purpose, you should use `signed char` and `unsigned char` to avoid problems. Even better `(u)int8_t` except for special cases (aliasing).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (I'm a beginner too)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    uint16_t i = 21; /* sample chosen because it's not a full mask */
    uint8_t k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j+=2){
        if(i & (1<<j)){
            k = k | 1<<l;
        }
        l++;
    }
    printf("Result: %d\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Admittedly at this point there are much more elegant solutions on offer, but helping you has helped me to improve too.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Thanks! I didn't even think about signing, but I've updated my example accordingly.

Comment: Better.  But, it's `uint16_t` without the extra underscore.  For the index you can use normal `int`; you don't need a fixed width variable. And you should replace `j++` by `j += 2` and remove the if (your check for even indices was wrong; it's odd right now)

Comment: Thanks again. u_int8_t was working, but I see now I'm learning from old materials & modern C consolidated that as uint8_t. As for the check - you're right. I misread the OP and assumed it was xyxyxyxy, not yxyxyxyx. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t foo(uint16_t p)
{
    uint16_t tmp;
    uint8_t mask;
    uint8_t result;

    result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        tmp     = p >> i;
        mask    = 1 << i;
        result  |= tmp & mask;
    }

    return result;
}
```

After optimization (improvement of around x4 with GCC 8.3 using -Ofast):

```c
uint8_t foo(uint16_t p)
{
    uint8_t mask;
    uint8_t result;

    result  = 0;
    mask    = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        result  |= p & mask;
        mask    <<= 1;
        p       >>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Example:

```c
p = 0xA3B4;
p = 0b1010_0011_1011_0100;
desired output  = 0b0001_0110;

i   = 0;

tmp = 0b1010_0011_1011_0100;
mask    = 0x1;
result  = 0 | (0b1010_0011_1011_0100 & 0x1) = 0b0;
i   = 1;

tmp = 0b101_0001_1101_1010;
mask    = 0x2;
result  = 0b0 | (0b101_0001_1101_1010 & 0x2) = 0b10;
i   = 2;

mask    = 0x4;
tmp = 0b10_1000_1110_1101;
result  = 0b10 | (0b10_1000_1110_1101 & 0x4) = 0b110;
i   = 3;

mask    = 0x8;
tmp = 0b1_0100_0111_0110;
result  = 0b110 | (0b1_0100_0111_0110 & 0x8) = 0b0110;
i   = 4;

mask    = 0x10;
tmp = 0b1010_0011_1011;
result  = 0b0110 | (0b1010_0011_1011 & 0x10) = 0b1_0110;
i   = 5;

mask    = 0x20;
tmp = 0b101_0001_1101;
result  = 0b1_0110 | (0b101_0001_1101 & 0x20) = 0b01_0110;
i   = 6;

mask    = 0x40;
tmp = 0b10_1000_1110;
result  = 0b01_0110 | (0b10_1000_1110 & 0x40) = 0b001_0110;
i   = 7;

mask    = 0x80;
tmp = 0b1_0100_0111;
result  = 0b001_0110 | (0b1_0100_0111 & 0x80) = 0b0001_0110;
i   = 8;

return  0b0001_0110;
```

Comment: `result |= tmp & mask;` is wrong. Instead, you need `if (tmp & 1) result |= mask;`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Fixed. Thanks, it wasn't that what I wanted to do, but I spotted the bug thanks to you anyway :)

Comment: Also recall `tmp` (`p`) has 16 bits, but in your loop you are never shifting more than 8 places. These are good problems to work though. It is always good to check your `result` after the function returns. Say you do `uint8_t ebyte = function (word);` then after the call you can simply do `int n = CHAR_BIT; while (n--) putchar ((ebyte >> n) & 1 ? '1' : '0'); putchar ('\n');` to output the binary result.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I prefer `printf("%#'.8b\n", ebyte);` with the appropriate previous setup. ;) https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220581/200418

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I don't need to shift more than 7 places. The farthest bit is the 14th, which goes to the 7th bit in the result.

Comment: Originally you didn't when you were using `tmp = p >> (2 * i);`, but now you are only shifting `p` by 8 places total with `tmp = p >> i;` in  your code.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Exactly. I had a mistake, and it is fixed now (after your first comment, actually). Thank you.  Actually I was trying to do this from the beginning, but I must've mixed some thoughts :/